# Can't get a simple horizontal menu working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm trying to set up an horizontal menu with background image an text button but it just never work under internet explorer, I want to cry...

This is what I do:

```
ul, li, ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list - style: none;
    border: none;
    background - image: none;
}
li {
    float: left;
}

ul.barrenoire {
    width: 790px;
    float: right;
    background - image: url('barrenoire.png'); /*790x24*/
    background - repeat: no - repeat;
    background - position: top right;
}
ul.barrenoire li {
    line - height: 0px; /*else height is too big*/
}
ul.barrenoire li a {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    width: 150px;
    line - height: 24px;
    text - align: center;
}
```

And

```
<ul class="barrenoire">
    <li><a style="width:30px"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="qsn">Qui sommes nous ?</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="p">Parrainnage</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="cs">Candidature spontannée</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="c">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="rn">Rejoignez-nous</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In chrome it's ok, but in IE the menu is horizontal, I don't find the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `list-style` instead of `list - style`

Comment: Works for me in IE11, JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4N9Qf/

Comment: You must remove all spaces before and after a dash `-`. Your CSS is invalid. Paste and validate it here: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: spaces have been added while posting on stackoverflow, they arn't in my css... I finaly changed the way I do that, now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

remove all spaces from the css rules (near the dashes) and also remove `float:right;` from `ul.barrenoire li a` style.

**EDIT**

if this wrecks your style on other browsers use a conditional stylesheet

**[Here is a reference](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)**

P.S. This worked for me on IE8...